# Charge ecr20 token for network fee instead of eth

Tags: web3js, nodejs, smart-contract-wallets

Is it possible to subtract the network fee from the user's ERC token instead of subtracting from the eth balance using web3js

Comment: you can do that but you will need to change the code of the ERC20 contract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, it's not possible on Ethereum (and BSC).**

Some lesser known EVM blockchains support meta transactions that possibly could allow that. Huobi Eco Chain would be an example, although I never tested this feature.